# Microsoft Access union query causing "Query too complex" error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have eight tables that contain info on changes being made to applications across the company. I only want to query and combine the rows for a subset of 200+ applications. To do this I am querying each table by application code (AAA,BBB etc.) and want to Union the results. When I use over 5 application codes, I get the error "Query to complex".

I know there is a more efficient way to do this, but the below is the best I've been able to do with my limited knowledge.

```sql
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-A July 5 to 7]   WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'AAA' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-B July 12 to 14] WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'AAA' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-C July 19 to 21] WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'AAA' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-D July 26 to 28] WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'AAA' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-08-A Aug 2 to 4]    WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'AAA' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-08-B Aug 9 to 11]   WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'AAA' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-08-C Aug 16 to 18]  WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'AAA' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-08-D Aug 23 to 25 Proposed] WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'AAA' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-A July 5 to 7]   WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'BBB' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-B July 12 to 14] WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'BBB' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-C July 19 to 21] WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'BBB' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-D July 26 to 28] WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'BBB' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-08-A Aug 2 to 4]    WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'BBB' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-08-B Aug 9 to 11]   WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'BBB' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-08-C Aug 16 to 18]  WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'BBB' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [2019-08-D Aug 23 to 25 Proposed] WHERE [Application code] LIKE 'BBB';
```

I would like to be able query all 200+ application codes at once, and in a more efficient manner than typing out the same string 8 times per code.

Comment: Are you using wildcards operators within the criteria for your `like` statements?

Comment: Everything else than combining the tables,creates denormalized data, what leads to porblems, like`Query to complex`or slow execution. If you need the seperate tables, you can emulate them by creating queries, containing that data (filter combined table on former tablename).

Comment: Usually, changes to apps are tracked by a`Version control systems (VCS)`. Any reason you do not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier approach could be to `union` the table data *before* applying the selection criteria, so that you only have to specify the criteria in **one** place e.g.:

```
select * from
(
    select * from [2019-07-A July 5 to 7]   union all 
    select * from [2019-07-B July 12 to 14] union all 
    select * from [2019-07-C July 19 to 21] union all 
    select * from [2019-07-D July 26 to 28] union all 
    select * from [2019-08-A Aug 2 to 4]    union all 
    select * from [2019-08-B Aug 9 to 11]   union all 
    select * from [2019-08-C Aug 16 to 18]  union all 
    select * from [2019-08-D Aug 23 to 25 Proposed]
) as t
where
    t.[Application code] like 'AAA' or
    t.[Application code] like 'BBB'
```

If you're **not** using wildcard operators within the criteria for the [`like`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931) statements, you could alternatively use the [`in`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/in-operator-d5a10cdc-cdb2-4854-be22-7abdeb5a3236) operator and provide a list of Application codes:

```
select * from
(
    select * from [2019-07-A July 5 to 7]   union all 
    select * from [2019-07-B July 12 to 14] union all 
    select * from [2019-07-C July 19 to 21] union all 
    select * from [2019-07-D July 26 to 28] union all 
    select * from [2019-08-A Aug 2 to 4]    union all 
    select * from [2019-08-B Aug 9 to 11]   union all 
    select * from [2019-08-C Aug 16 to 18]  union all 
    select * from [2019-08-D Aug 23 to 25 Proposed]
) as t
where
    t.[Application code] in ('AAA', 'BBB')
```

Alternatively, you could create a table containing all of the Application Codes you wish to return (in the following example, I've called such table `ApplicationCodes` containing a single field called `Code`), and then use a simple join to apply the filtering implicitly, e.g.:

```
select * from
(
    select * from [2019-07-A July 5 to 7]   union all 
    select * from [2019-07-B July 12 to 14] union all 
    select * from [2019-07-C July 19 to 21] union all 
    select * from [2019-07-D July 26 to 28] union all 
    select * from [2019-08-A Aug 2 to 4]    union all 
    select * from [2019-08-B Aug 9 to 11]   union all 
    select * from [2019-08-C Aug 16 to 18]  union all 
    select * from [2019-08-D Aug 23 to 25 Proposed]
) as t 
inner join ApplicationCodes on t.[Application code] = ApplicationCodes.Code
```

Comment: Not sure what wildcard operators are (I'm not a dev, and have no sql experience). Your last suggestion with the additional table containing the app codes we want to query worked like a charm!  Thank you for the help, and quick reply

Comment: You're welcome. Click on the link in my answer to the documentation for the `like` operator and you'll see the available wildcard operators (such as `*`, `?`, `#` etc) that you may use in the pattern supplied to the `like` operator.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you create a table that has all the applications in it then you could do just 8 queries

```
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-A July 5 to 7] f, [Applications]  a 
 WHERE f.[Application code] = a.[Application code] UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-B July 12 to 14] f, [Applications]  a 
 WHERE f.[Application code] = a.[Application code] UNION ALL
etc...
```

If you don't like that you could try an IN clause

```
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-A July 5 to 7]   WHERE [Application code] IN 
( 'AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD', etc...) UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM [2019-07-B July 12 to 14] WHERE [Application code] IN 
( 'AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD', etc...) UNION ALL ALL
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest using joins over a cartesian product & where clause.

Comment: I missunderstood your answer. I thought you want to combine the tables like my answer does, not just extract applications to a new table.

Answer (score 0):

Table names that contain dates or sequence numbers and the same same fields, usually should be combined with the table-name as additional porperty.

Create a table (e.g. ApplicationChanges) with the fields of of your unioned tables and add an addtional field`ChangedAt`that will hold the old table name.
Maybe the old tables contain a date-field, that shows date ChangedAt, then you can omit the table-name and query which dates belong to whis table.

Then use @LeeMacs query to populate the new table:

```sql
INSERT INTO ApplicationChanges
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [2019-07-A July 5 to 7].*
          , '[2019-07-A July 5 to 7]' AS ChangedAt
        FROM
            [2019-07-A July 5 to 7]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            [2019-07-B July 12 to 14].*
          , '[2019-07-B July 12 to 14]' AS ChangedAt
        FROM
            [2019-07-B July 12 to 14]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            [2019-07-C July 19 to 21].*
          , '[2019-07-C July 19 to 21]' AS ChangedAt
        FROM
            [2019-07-C July 19 to 21]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            [2019-07-D July 26 to 28]*
          , '[2019-07-D July 26 to 28]' AS ChangedAt
        FROM
            [2019-07-D July 26 to 28]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            [2019-08-A Aug 2 to 4].*
          , '[2019-08-A Aug 2 to 4]' AS ChangedAt
        FROM
            [2019-08-A Aug 2 to 4]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            [2019-08-B Aug 9 to 11].*
          , '[2019-08-B Aug 9 to 11]' AS ChangedAt
        FROM
            [2019-08-B Aug 9 to 11]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            [2019-08-C Aug 16 to 18].*
          , '[2019-08-C Aug 16 to 18]' AS ChangedAt
        FROM
            [2019-08-C Aug 16 to 18]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            [2019-08-D Aug 23 to 25 Proposed].*
          , '[2019-08-D Aug 23 to 25 Proposed]' AS ChangedAt
        FROM
            [2019-08-D Aug 23 to 25 Proposed]
    )
    AS t
```

If you need the old data structure, create queries for each former table, with the ChangedAt as criteria.
E.g. table`[2019-07-A July 5 to 7]`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    ApplicationChanges
WHERE
    ChangedAt = '[2019-07-A July 5 to 7]'
    AND [Application code] IN ('AAA'
                             , 'BBB');
```

No more need for slow union-queries,